# dirscancb problem show in log file

Tags: 12.04

In the log file of my Ubuntu 12.04 installation, there are long list of log entries as below:

rpc.idmapd[818]: dirscancb: open(/run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/clntfa): No such file or directory
rpc.idmapd[818]: dirscancb: open(/run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/clntfb): No such file or directory

What is wrong with my installation? How to revolve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug but these messages are harmless. It is related to NFS and I found this description regarding the same problem (though related to [Redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=726472)):

> The daemon `rpc.idmapd` scans the `/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs/nfs/` directory
>       periodically looking for NFS client mounts to communicate to. The daemon
>       tried to open communication with a client mount but it disappeared in
>       between looking for directory entries and opening them. NFS mount was
>       umounted just before `rpc.idmapd` tried to communicate with it. This
>       behavior is usually seen when autofs is configured on the system.

This needs to be reported here: http://linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/Reporting_bugs

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind for the kind reply. The bug has been submitted following the link provided.